# JOIN query to DBF via VBA

Tags: sql, vba, join, inner-join, dbf

I apologize if this has been asked but i can't find where i'm going wrong here.

I need to query (2) dbf tables AP and VENDOR which contain vendors and payables. I need to get a list of all the payables entered between two specified dates. ap_vendor contains the vendor ID in the AP table and v_vendor contains the vendor ID in the vendor table.

I need to use a join to return the vendor name and the amount which are in separate tables.

This is my query:

```
SELECT a.ap_invamt, a.ap_invoice, b.v_name 
          FROM AP a JOIN VENDOR b 
          ON a.ap_vendor = b.v_vendor
```

I need to add a WHERE clause as well but i cant even get this part to run.

Keep getting error: "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Comment: LEFT JOIN does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other SQL dialects, you cannot use just the word JOIN to specify an inner join in Access (JET) SQL. You have to use both keywords: a INNER JOIN b.

Interestingly enough, I just tested it and JET does allow for LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN, without the OUTER keyword.

Change your query to read FROM AP a INNER JOIN Vendor b and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Adding "INNER" before "JOIN" now I get a "No value given for one or more required parameters". So it seems like the JOIN is no longer the issue. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: That sounds like the error you might get if one of the field names in the query doesn’t match the field names in the table – – in other words, if you miss spell something, jet thinks you’re trying to pass that as a parameter.SQL server, on the other hand, treated as a syntax error. Give those a check and let me know what happens.

Comment: Yup the second issue was my stupid mistake. I had a field name incorrect in my string. a.ap_vendor should have been a.v_vendor.

Comment: Glad to help.That "parameter" problem takes forever to figure out the first time because there is nothing in the syntax indicating something is a praramter. (Unlike the @ in Sql Server, for example)